# Setting for figure.patch.set_facecolor(somecolor) in matplotlibrc

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to set a permanent facecolor for all my plots. I've figured out the way to do this temporarily:

```
fig.patch.set_facecolor('somecolor')
```

I want to make this setting permanent, and I understand the way to do that is by editing the matplotlibrc file, but I'm not able to find the exact setting that will do this. Does anyone have any idea which config setting will allow me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can open your `~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc` file in the Command Line with a text editor like Nano or Vim.

In your `~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc` file you should add the following:

`figure.facecolor : somecolor`

This will make it so that all of your figures will have this facecolor by default.